# Pseudo selector not working on submit

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me why my pseudo selector is not working?

I thought it would be pretty straightforward..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>      
    <head>
        <title>test</title> 
    </head>

<body>

    <form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="register_post.php" >
        <p class="registerSubmit">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </p>
    </form> 

    <style>
        .registerSubmit #submit {
            background: white;
        }

        .registerSubmit #submit :hover {
            background: red;
        }
    <style>

</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate it.. thanks.

Comment: `#submit:hover`, otherwise you're selecting all elements inside `#submit`.

Comment: If that answers your question please just delete the post.

Comment: Apply :hover to submit only, not the entire form.

Comment: Actually the class before #submit made absolutely no difference. It was just the space before :hover that made it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this code:

```
    <style>
        .registerSubmit #submit {
            background: white;
        }

        .registerSubmit #submit:hover {
            background: red;
        }
    <style>
```

See one more time:

```
.registerSubmit #submit:hover {
```

look one last time:

```
#submit:hover {
```

Are Achieve see the space?

Bye!

Comment: Not sure what he meant, but if he meant 'get rid of the space before ':hover' ' then this is the right answer. I though CSS was not so sensitive to whitespace..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NfYrj/

Apply `:hover` to `submit` only, not the entire `form`.

```
#submit:hover {
     background: red;
 }
```